# Multiplicities of the eigenvalues of a perturbed matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $S$ is a symmetric and positive definite matrix in $\mathcal{R}^{n\times n}$. Suppose that $D$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal $[1,a^{-1},\cdots,a^{-n+1}]$ for some positive real $a$. If S has $n$ different eigenvalues, then is it true that $DS$ has $n$ different eigenvalues? What can be said about the eigenvalues of $DS$ or their multiplicities?

Comment: What is $A$? is $A=S$?

Comment: Yes, sorry it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider, e.g. the case $0<a<1$ and $S=D^{-1}$.

I don't know what can be said about the multiplicities of the eigenvalues of $DS$ in general, but we do know that all eigenvalues of $DS$ are positive, as $DS$ is similar to $D^{1/2}SD^{1/2}$, which is positive definite.

Comment: What if we know $S$ explicitly? Namely, the $i,j$ entrance of $S$ is given by $S_{i,j}=(i+j)!/(i!j!)$. This is, S is the so-called Pascal matrix.